# Mudar a quantidade de casas decimais na estrutura da tabela (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Possuo 3 campos em uma tabela que usam o "Tipo de dados" definidos como "decimal(15, 2)" e eu precisa alterar (via código) para "decimal(15, 3)".

Ou seja, mudar de 2 casas decimais para 3.

Preciso fazer via código, pois tenho q alterar todos meus clientes... e ficaria inviável mudar campo por campo na estrutura de cada cliente.

Comment: Já tentou usar o SQL management studio? Ele faz esse script pra vc...

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o comando [`ALTER TABLE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-BR/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
ALTER TABLE NomeDaTabela ALTER COLUMN NomeDaColuna decimal(16,3);
```

Veja que aqui usei `(16,3)`, porque já tinha (15,2), ou seja, tinha "15 digitos, sendo 2 reservados para os decimais" e se fizer `(15,3)` vai perder um dígito inteiro (antes do ponto), pode até receber uma mensagem de dados truncados, assim fica com "16 digitos, sendo 3 para decimais", ou seja, continua com 15 inteiros (antes do ponto).

Para ficar mais claro "visualmente":

```
<------ 15 ------>
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNN.NN  -> decimal (15,2)
NNNNNNNNNNNNNN.NNN  -> decimal (15,3) perde 1 dígito inteiro
```

Comment: Obg amigo, resolveu alem dos que precisava

Comment: por nada, não esqueça de escolher a resposta nesse caso ;)